# ActiveX component cannot be created for COM component in release mode (VS2010 specific)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, com, activex, atl

I have an ATL COM component(.exe) (VC++ ) in VS2008. Through VB6 client, i use CreateObject and get the object.

But once the component is updated to VS2010 SP1, the VB6 client no longer is able to create the COM object.

If I compile the VS2010 COM component in debug mode and get the .exe, VB6 client is working fine. 
In release mode, .exe is generated without any errors, and VB6 client fails saying ActiveX component cannot be created.

Please help me in resloving this.

Comment: What do you see debugging your release build of EXE COM server? Anything reaches you? You should be able to see at least something and then step from there.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are testing the Release build on *another* machine.  Which doesn't have the C++ runtime support DLLs installed.

Comment: analyzing further, i was able to debug Project.cpp Main method. Here in debug mode, '_Module.RegisterClassObjects' goes smoothly. But in release mode, it goes into another method 'CreateInstance' in atlcom.h and it fails @ 'p->_AtlInitialConstruct();' . Hope some body can tell why this is happening or any msitake in project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Finding out why COM refuses to create an instance of some CoClass is really a PITA. All you get is some generic error code that won't help you very much. If you use the run-time library via Dlls, you should check whether those can be found outside of the debugger. I use the COM/OLE viewer to check whether I can create objects of a CoClass, so that I can rule out that the problem has anything to do with VB. 
Good luck.

Stuart

Comment: I added a msgbox in the first line of the constructor i am calling, MessageBoxW( NULL,(LPCWSTR)L"paused",(LPCWSTR)L"paused",MB_OK ); but it is not hit in release mode. This is failing on my machine also, The exe is not started, hence i am unable to debug.